# series of a function

Tags: matlab, series

i have problem solving a series of a function.

how should i solve series like  Σ  F(k)*F(k-1) ?

actually i want to solve the below series in Matlab

"[image of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYff.jpg)"

it's only dependent of K variable.

i tried by defining a function as bellow and saving it as an .m file (for testing i simplified it by neglecting B)

```
 function out = teta(x) 
    if x==9./5
        out=(25./(36*1));
    else
        out=(10./(9.*1.*x.*(x-1))).*(x-9./5).*teta(x-9./5);
    end
```

and wrote this in the main file:

```
sum(teta(18/5:9/5:72/5))
```

as i want a sum of the serie from k=18/5 to 72/5

when i run it i get these errors:

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in teta (line 2)
>
> if x==9./5

and

> Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the program.
>   Error in teta (line 5)
>
> `out=(10./(9*1.*x.*(x-1))).*(x-9./5).*teta(x-9./5);`

so where i'm wrong and "how should i solve these kind of series?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you shouldn't an equality test on a floating double precision number, but instead compare the difference to a small threshold value.

Not using a vectorised approach (feel free to vectorise if you so desire), the following works:

```
function out = teta(x) 

    if abs(x-9/5)<1e-3
        out=25/36;
    else
        out=(10/(9*x*(x-1)))*(x-9/5)*teta(x-9/5);
    end
```

and then use it as such:

```
kk = 18/5:9/5:72/5;
teta_vec = zeros(size(kk));
for k=1:length(kk)
    teta_vec(k) = teta(kk(k));
end
```

which gives me:

```
>> sum(teta_vec)
ans =  0.17714
```